# Pandas.Index.isin() fails with large data set

Tags: pandas, debugging, dataframe, indexing

Here is an example

Create a table with 100M identical rows:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([('20170101', 'TULIP', 'FLOWER')] * 100000000, columns = ['DATE', 'NAME', 'TYPE'])
```

Set the first 2 columns as index:

```
>>> df.set_index(['DATE', 'NAME'], inplace=True)
```

Then check if the index is in `[('20170101', 'TULIP')]`, which should be true for all rows:

```
>>> df.index.isin([('20170101', 'TULIP')])
array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So the result Pandas gives is wrong - it has all of them to be `False`. In fact, if I only check the first 1M rows, it gives the right result:

```
>>> df[:1000000].index.isin([('20170101', 'TULIP')])
array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Is this a bug in Pandas? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug. I think something goes awry around [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L414) and internally `np.in1d` gets used instead. Indeed, `np.in1d(df[:1000000].index.values, [('20170101', 'TULIP')])` gives an array of `False` values.

Comment: See this related [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16012) with `isIn` and >1m records.

Comment: @JanTrienes, intersting - so do you still think I should report to Pandas for a bug report or that's a known but not fixable issue?

Comment: this is already fixed for 0.21: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Jeff in his comment on the OP, this issue will be fixed in release 0.21.